# Nested transaction support in J2EE 1.4

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, transactions, ejb

I read that EJB 2.x spec does not support nested transactions.
But logically think we can call an EJB method that has REQUIRES_NEW txn attribute from another EJB method that acutally started a transaction
Isn't this a valid case. If valid isn't this what is called nested transactions.

Please point me if I am missing anything here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `REQUIRES_NEW` propagation means:

> Create a new transaction, suspend the
>   current transaction if one exists.

So the transactions would not be nested - the first one is suspended, shunted out of the way, and a new, unrelated, transaction is started.

You don't really need to nest the transactions themselves, you just need to ensure that each time you pass through a transactional boundary, you inherit the existing transaction (or start a new one). The default propagation `PROPAGATION_REQUIRED` is generally good enough.

Interestingly, JDBC 3.0 did introduce the concept of nested transactions, but the EBJ spec has yet to catch up.